# How to make all array elements accessible

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I've been trying to make the elements of an array accessible, but I've had no success so far. This is the code, and I've created it due to the given assignment.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

class Matrix_1D
{
private:
    int *p2values;
    int num_elements;
public:
    Matrix_1D(int *p2v, int n); // CTOR
    ~Matrix_1D(); // DTOR
    void show();
};

Matrix_1D::Matrix_1D(int *p2v, int n)
{
    n = sizeof(p2v)/sizeof(int); // the problem comes from the fact that sizeof(p2v) = 4 bytes, and not the length of the entire array!!!
    num_elements = n;
    p2values = new int [n];
    for(int i = 0; i<num_elements; i++)
        p2values[i] = p2v[i];
}

Matrix_1D::~Matrix_1D()
{
    delete [] p2values;
}

void Matrix_1D::show()
{
    for(int i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
        cout << p2values[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int array_a[] = {5,3,5};

    Matrix_1D fkt_1D_a(array_a, sizeof(array_a)/sizeof(int));

    fkt_1D_a.show();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The sizeof(AnyPointer) is a constant value (depending on the target platform)

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Even though there's an accepted answer, I'm voting to close because it's not clear at all what "make the elements of an array accessible" is supposed to mean. You haven't explained what you're trying to accomplish, and in which way it's not working. Since it's not clear what's being asked and answered, it's not useful Q&A for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Matrix_1D::Matrix_1D(int *p2v, int n)
{
    n = sizeof(p2v)/sizeof(int); // the problem comes from the fact that sizeof(p2v) = 4 bytes, and not the length of the entire array!!!
    num_elements = n;
    p2values = new int [n];
    for(int i = 0; i<num_elements; i++)
        p2values[i] = p2v[i];
}
```

As you state the `sizeof p2v` is the size of the pointer so you have no idea how large the array is. Instead, use the parameter that is passed in and don't overwrite it:

```
Matrix_1D::Matrix_1D(int *p2v, int n)
{
    // you don't need the first line at all.
    num_elements = n;
    p2values = new int [n];
    for(int i = 0; i<num_elements; i++)
        p2values[i] = p2v[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper C++ way to get the size of your `int` array is to use a template:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
size_t size(T (&)[N]) {
    return N;  // size of array
}
```